# React doesn't re-render component on state change

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with a search field and a list of items, where I am using that value from search field to filter through the array of items and update the list. This is are the parts of the component responsible for that:

```
this.state = {
  tasks: null,
  unfilteredTasks: null,
};

componentDidMount() {
    this.gateway.loadTasks().then(result => {
        this.setState({tasks: result, unfilteredTasks: result})
    })
}

onSearchChange(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const propsToCheck = ['task.text', 'type', 'status', 'topic.name'];
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const tasks = prevState.unfilteredTasks.filter(obj => checkObjectContainsValue(obj, value)(propsToCheck));
      return {tasks: tasks};
    })
  }

render() {
    return <TasksPresentation
      <TasksList
        tasks={this.state.tasks}
        onSearchChange={(event) => this.onSearchChange(event)}>
      </TasksList>
    </TasksPresentation>
  }
```

With this I can see in the developer tools that the state of the component is being changed and that the tasks list is being filtered, but the lists is not being re-rendered. Why is that, how can I fix this?

**Update**

On inspecting further down the component chain. I can see that the tas list table component that is responsible for rendering of the list is a class component that uses prop `rows` which is the `tasks` list being send down from the parent component, to build state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state.data = this.transformRows(props.rows)
  }
```

Comment: Does `TaskList` render props directly or it keeps an internal state as well? In this case you need to react appropriately with something like https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: This code looks alright. Do you have code for TaskList? Is it using `props.tasks` directly in render? If you assign props.tasks to this.state.tasks in lets say constructor or componentWillMount of TaskList, and use it in render, then the update won't be visible.

Comment: I have updated the question. Looks like the child component that renders the list is a class component that builds it's state with prop rows that gets tasks from the parent component.

Comment: So you have mentioned the error `this.state.data = this.transformRows(props.rows)`.
either directly use props, or in `componentDidUpdate` sync the new props with local state